# Delete older than 30 days if not 1st of month

Tags: mysql, bash, backup

I have this in a cron job to remove databases older than 30 days:

```
find /my/backup/path/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

How can I modify this to only delete the files if the backup was not taken on the first of the month?

E.G. I want have a daily backup of databases (for one month only) PLUS a backup for each month:

- Jan/1 backup
- Feb/1 backup
- Mar/6 backups (as it's currently 6th March)

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
rm_if_not_on_1st() {
  [ "$(stat -c %y "$1" | cut -c9-10)" = "01" ] || rm "$1"
}
export -f rm_if_not_on_1st

find /my/backup/path/* -mtime +30 -exec bash -c 'rm_if_not_on_1st "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: This should work with any valid file name. `{}` is passed as a true parameter to the shell, not dynamically inserted into the command.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to modify your "find" command/cron job but you could:

- create another cron job that moves the monthly backup file (taken on 1st of  month) to another directory called say /my/backup/monthly_backups. Then when your find / remove cron job runs it won't find the one taken on 1st of the month
- another option is to modify the backup script to name monthly backups differently so that they then don't match the "find" criteria in the cron job and so won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`-exec` is a filter, too: the exit status of the executed command is the result of the primary. I'll adapt [Alfe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42624330/1126841) to demonstrate:

```
date_is_not_the_first () {
  [ "$(stat -c %y "$1" | cut -c9-10)" != 01 ]
}

find /my/backup/path/* -mtime +30 -exec bash -c 'date_is_not_the_first "$1"' _ {} \; -delete
```

The `-delete` option only applies if `-mtime` is true and the `-exec` command has a zero exit status.